# Using a UniformGrid inside of a Button control in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want the content of a Button control to contain a uniform grid. However, the Button control doesn't seem to allow its child content control to Stretch. My UniformGrid is always squeezed down to fit its own contents. It allows me to set the width, but it won't auto stretch even if I set the HorizontalAlignment explicitly. What am I missing?

```
        <Button Margin="0,4,0,4">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}" Focusable="False">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Zones.Count}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <wpfApplication2:ControllerZoneControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Button>
```

I can force the width using the following, but it seems hacky to me.

```
 <UniformGrid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}" Columns="{Binding Zones.Count}" />
```

Comment: Can you post please the code from your "ControllerZoneControl" ?

Comment: Your "hack" is often enough the correct solution. But can't you set the Button's `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`?

Comment: That was the missing piece to the puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

Of all things I forgot to try...setting the button's HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch was the fix.